# Why does Featured Images not load in the backed?

Tags: functions

Here's my code in the functions.php file:

```
<?php
    // Excerpt Length Control
    function set_excerpt_length(){
      return 85;
    }

    // Theme stream_support
    function wpb_theme_setup(){
      add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' ); 
    }

    add_filter('excerpt_length', 'set_excerpt_length');
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks!

ALSO! I notice that the functions.php never has a closing ?> - how come?

Comment: Do you mean to say you are not able to view the featured image option in wp-admin?

Comment: Yes that is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code excerpt you have a function to add theme support for post thumbnails but you don't include a line where you actually run it. Can you confirm that you are also executing wpb_theme_setup() as well as defining it?  If it's the only thing in the function, you could just call `add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );` on its own (that is, remove the wrapping function).

The closing ?> is not compulsory in PHP

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that i was missing the action:

```
  add_action('after_setup_theme','wpb_theme_setup');
```